# how to calculate the sum of column values for each similiar rows using Ant Design Table

Tags: reactjs, sum, aggregation, ant-design-pro

I want to calculate the sum of column values "amount" for each similiar rows that have the same name using Ant design Table

I tried reduce function

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You need to provide your code if you want to get better answers. but very generically it should work like this:

```
const data = [
  { name: "Toyota", amount: 10 },
  { name: "Toyota", amount: 20 },
  { name: "BMW", amount: 50 },
];

const grouping = data.reduce((acc, car) => {
  if (!acc[car.name]) {
    acc[car.name] = { ...car };
  } else {
    acc[car.name].amount += car.amount;
  }
  return acc;
}, {});

const tableValues = Object.values(grouping);

<Table dataSource={result} ....>
```

Comment: export interface TradeData {
  id: number;
  name: String;
  amount: number;
}

Comment: I am using typescript

Comment: did my code worked for you? the interface you provided is very similar to my generic solution.